# pam_limits: Operation not permitted for sshd

Tags: ssh, pam, ulimit

Debian 8.0, pam 1.1.8-3.1, sshd 1:6.7p1-5.

I'm trying to permanently increase the maximum number of open files.

In `/etc/pam.d/` I've got:

```
/etc/pam.d# grep pam_limits.so *
atd:session    required   pam_limits.so
common-session:session required pam_limits.so
common-session-noninteractive:session required pam_limits.so
cron:session    required   pam_limits.so
login:session    required   pam_limits.so
runuser:session         required        pam_limits.so
sshd:session    required     pam_limits.so
su:session    required   pam_limits.so
```

In `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*       hard    nofile  20000500
*       soft    nofile  20000500
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
UsePAM yes
```

In `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.file-max = 20000500
```

I've rebooted the OS and what I'm seeing in `/var/log/auth.log` is:

> sshd[807]: pam_limits(sshd:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile'
>   to soft=20000500, hard=20000500: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0

Same thing trying to do `ulimit -Hn 20000500` as `root`:

> bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Using trial-and-error, I've found the maximum number I can give `ulimit -Hn` without failing: 1048576. Why exactly this number and where does it come from?

P.S. When it says "operation not permitted", how do I know who decides? I assume the code within pam_limits.so is trying to set the limits, but who does actually refuse? Is it the PAM system which possibly takes over the whole security system in the OS?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/641899/ulimit-file-descriptor-limits-not-being-applied-for-particular-process/641904#641904

Comment: @c4f4t0r yeah it's not a production box so it doesn't really matter, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is no a recommend, I would like to say, you cannot do that. if you looking this other answer.

[can't log in when nofile is set to unlimited in /etc/security/limits.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/583820/cant-log-in-when-nofile-is-set-to-unlimited-in-etc-security-limits-conf/583840#583840)

```
man proc

   /proc/sys/fs/file-max
          This file defines a system-wide limit on the number of open files for all processes.  (See also setrlimit(2), which can be used by a process to set the per-
          process  limit,  RLIMIT_NOFILE,  on the number of files it may open.)  If you get lots of error messages in the kernel log about running out of file handles
          (look for "VFS: file-max limit <number> reached"), try increasing this value:

              echo 100000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max

          The kernel constant NR_OPEN imposes an upper limit on the value that may be placed in file-max.

          If you increase /proc/sys/fs/file-max, be sure to increase /proc/sys/fs/inode-max to 3-4 times the new value of /proc/sys/fs/file-max, or you will  run  out
          of inodes.

          Privileged processes (CAP_SYS_ADMIN) can override the file-max limit.
```

`ulimit` is a limit for a user, isn't normale set the same number in the global setting, is like a user can use all files in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing hardcoded, simply set sysctl_nr_open via fs.nr_open=5242880 and
re-do sysctl -p/login, your limit is now 5m. file-max needs to be the same
value.

Comment: doesn't work on Amazon linux at least. I also needed this: http://serverfault.com/a/702074/58945